how to store logs in wso2 api manager logs in oracle database
i have tried appenders concept to store logs in databasein wso2 api manager show below
appender.jdbc.type = JDBC
appender.jdbc.name = jdbc
appender.jdbc.connectionSource.driverClassName = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
appender.jdbc.connectionSource.type = DriverManager
appender.jdbc.connectionSource.connectionString = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe
appender.jdbc.connectionSource.userName=system
appender.jdbc.connectionSource.password=Finextian@1
appender.jdbc.tableName=LOGS
appender.jdbc.ignoreExceptions=false
appender.jdbc.columnConfigs[0].type = COLUMN 
appender.jdbc.columnConfigs[0].name = DATE 
appender.jdbc.columnConfigs[0].pattern = %d 
appender.jdbc.columnConfigs[0].isUnicode =false
appender.jdbc.columnConfigs[1].type = COLUMN
appender.jdbc.columnConfigs[1].name = TENANT_ID
appender.jdbc.columnConfigs[1].pattern =%tenantId
appender.jdbc.columnConfigs[1].isUnicode =false
appender.jdbc.columnConfigs[2].type = COLUMN
appender.jdbc.columnConfigs[2].name = LEVEL
appender.jdbc.columnConfigs[2].pattern =%5p
appender.jdbc.columnConfigs[2].isUnicode =false
appender.jdbc.columnConfigs[3].type = COLUMN
appender.jdbc.columnConfigs[3].name = LOGGER
appender.jdbc.columnConfigs[3].pattern =%c
appender.jdbc.columnConfigs[3].isUnicode =false
appender.jdbc.columnConfigs[4].type = COLUMN
appender.jdbc.columnConfigs[4].name = MESSAGE
appender.jdbc.columnConfigs[4].pattern =%mm%ex%n
appender.jdbc.columnConfigs[4].isUnicode =false
logger.BasicHandler.appenderRef.jdbc.ref = jdbc`



for this concept am not getting any issues in console .but logs are not stored into database. Is there any other way to store logs into database .
my expectation is to store wso2 Api manager Api logs into oracle database``

What is the APIM version used here? Ideally, this should work. Did you add the Oracle JDBC driver to the repository/components/lib location inside the product? This is needed to establish the connection with the database. Also, what is the Oracle db version used here? You need to make sure the driver is compatible with that version.
Furthermore, you need to add jdbc as one of the appenders in the log4j2 properties file under appenders. For example,
appenders = jdbc, CARBON_CONSOLE, CARBON_LOGFILE, ATOMIKOS_LOGFILE, CARBON_TRACE_LOGFILE, DELETE_EVENT_LOGFILE, TRANSACTION_LOGFILE, osgi


yeah in appenders i have added above line also but its not working. In my machine am using wao2 api manger version 4.2.0 and oracle driver added in the library folder
